# Trying to convert a timestamp using javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, converters

is there a way to convert a complex time stamp to a simple one using javascript? i'd like to go from:

```
06-Feb-14 3:15 AM EST
```

to just:

```
3:16 AM
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) . You'll have good functionality to do what you need.

One example.

```
var mydate = Date.parse('2012-02-18 14:28:32');
var result = mydate.toString('dddd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much